trouble with array usage
This is my prompt:

Write a program that reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 0 to 50 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered. Indicate the end of the input by a value outside of the range. After all input has been processed, print all of the values (with the number of occurrences) that were entered one or more times.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Occurrence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numArray = new int[51];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;

        // lets user enter numbers, out of range numbers to stop
        while (num > 0 || num < 50) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer between 0-50, enter " + "out of range\nto stop:");
            num = scan.nextInt();
        }
        if (num < 0 || num > 50)
            System.out.println("you have stopped");

        // prints out occurences of numbers
        for (int count = 0; count < 51; count++) {
            System.out.print(count);
            System.out.print(": \n" + numArray[count]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

This is what I have so far. I know a lot of it is wrong because I haven't grasped arrays yet.
I am also having trouble getting the program to stop taking in values when it is outside of the range of (0,50). I'm not sure why my conditions don't work.

Every number is more than 0 or less than 50.

The while condition should use && and not ||, i.e:
while (num > 0 && num < 50) {

For logical operator ||, just one of the conditions needs to be true, so, for example, if num is -1 (negative one) then it is not greater than 0 (zero) but still it is less than 50 which means that the while loop continues whereas for operator && both conditions need to be true, i.e. num needs to be both greater than 0 and less than 50. Also, since the acceptable range is 0 to 50 inclusive, the while loop condition should be:
while (num >= 0 && num <= 50) {

Inside the while loop, you aren't doing anything with num. Each element of numArray contains the number of times the element's index was entered by the user. So, for example, if the user enters the number 12 then you want to increment the value of the element in numArray at index 12, i.e:
numArray[num]++;

After fixing the while loop condition, there is no need for the if statement after the while loop since the loop will exit only when num is not in the accepted range.
I think you made a mistake regarding the way you print the results. I think you mean the following:
System.out.println(count + ": " + numArray[count]);

Also, the question states that you need to print only those numbers whose count is greater than zero, therefore you need to add an if statement in the for loop.
Here is the corrected code:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Occurrence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numArray = new int[51];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;

        // lets user enter numbers, out of range numbers to stop
        while (num >= 0 && num <= 50) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer between 0-50, enter " + "out of range\nto stop:");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            if (num >= 0  &&  num <= 50) {
                numArray[num]++;
            }
        }

        // prints out occurrences of numbers
        for (int count = 0; count < 51; count++) {
            if (numArray[count] > 0) {
                System.out.println(count + ": " + numArray[count]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

Output from a sample run of the above code:
Enter an integer between 0-50, enter out of range
to stop:
2
Enter an integer between 0-50, enter out of range
to stop:
99
2: 1


thank you very much! you explained better than my professor

How the && works - Every condition should be true
When two or more conditions are separated by &&, the total result will be only true if all the conditions are true. If any one of the conditions is false then the total result will be false.
int age = 0;
int height = 0;
int weight = 0;

boolean isEligible = (age > 25) && (height > 170) && (weight > 60); // eligibility criteria


Case - 1

    age = 30;
    height = 177;
    weight = 65;
    
    (age > 25) => true
    (height > 170) => true
    (weight > 60) => true
    
    // All the conditions are true, so the total result will be true


Case - 2

    age = 30;
    height = 177;
    weight = 60;
    
    (age > 25) => true
    (height > 170) => true
    (weight > 60) => false
    
    // weight is not greater than 60 which makes that condition false
    // Since any one of the conditions is false, the total result "isEligible" will be false

How the || works - Any one of the conditions should be true
When two or more conditions are separated by ||, the total result will be true if any one of the conditions is true. So, if there are five conditions separated by || and if the first condition itself is true, the other conditions won't be checked and the total result will be true. Only if all the conditions are false then the total result will be false.
int sportsScore = 0;
int subjectScore = 0;

boolean isEligible = (sportsScore > 6) || (subjectScore > 35); // eligibility criteria


Case - 1

    sportsScore = 7;
    subjectScore = 30;
    
    (sportsScore > 6) => true
    (subjectScore > 35) => false
    
    // As the first condition is true the second one won't be checked and total result will be true


Case - 2

    sportsScore = 6;
    subjectScore = 36;
    
    (sportsScore > 6) => false
    (subjectScore > 35) => true
    
    // Even if the first condition is false, the second one will be checked, and since it is true the total result will be true


Case - 3

    sportsScore = 6;
    subjectScore = 35;
    
    (sportsScore > 6) => false
    (subjectScore > 35) => false
    
    // Since both the conditions are false, the total result will also be false

So the same applies for the while loop, it will run until the condition is true. Now when you give the condition as (num > 0 || num < 50) and if you enter a number say -1 the first condition is false, but the second condition is true so since the total result is true the loop won't stop. That's why you need to use && as mentioned by @Abra. The rest of the logic required is already mentioned in the answer provided by @Abra.

i see this makes so much more sense, thank you!
